# Reading .txt file into C program

Tags: c

I'm able to get the program to open the file, but I'm having trouble getting it to read the information. It needs to run the data line by line, but it keeps getting caught by my "Error reading data" loop. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getdata(FILE *data, int *empid, int *dept, float *paygr, int *exe, int *hours);
void calcdata(float paygr, int exe, int hours, float *pay, float *overpay, float *tpay);
void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, int exe, int hours, float pay, float overpay, float tpay);

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *data;
    int empid;
    int dept;
    float paygr;
    int exe;
    int hours;
    float pay;
    float overpay;
    float tpay;

    data = fopen("emp_data.txt", "r");

    if (data == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Could not open input file\a\n");
        exit(101);
    }

    while (getdata(data, &empid, &dept, &paygr, &exe, &hours)) 
    {
        calcdata(paygr, exe, hours, &pay, &overpay, &tpay);
        printdata(empid, dept, paygr, exe, hours, pay, overpay, tpay);
    }

    fclose(data);

    return 0;
}

int getdata(FILE *data, int* empid, int* dept, float *paygr, int *exe, int *hours) 
{
    int ioResult;

    ioResult = fscanf(data, "%d%d%f%d%d", empid, dept, paygr, exe, hours);
    if (ioResult == EOF) 
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else if (ioResult != 5) 
    {
        printf("\aError reading data\n");
        return 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void calcdata(float paygr, int exe, int hours, float *pay, float *overpay, float *tpay) 
{
    int overhrs;

    if (exe == 'N' && hours > 40) 
    {
        overhrs = hours - 40;
        *tpay = (paygr * (hours - overhrs)) + (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
        *pay = (hours - overhrs) * paygr;
        *overpay = (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
    } 
    else 
    {
        *tpay = hours * paygr;
        *pay = hours * paygr;
        *overpay = 0.0;
    }
}

void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, int exe, int hours, float pay, float overpay, float tpay) 
{
    printf("%d %d %2f %d %d %2f %2f %2f\n", empid,  dept,  paygr, exe, hours, pay, overpay, tpay);
}
```

Here's the text from emp_data.txt

```
205     14  7.54    N   45

3498    64  17.98   Y   38

1328    38  25.75   Y   49

9054    76  10.43   N   42

213     64  8.29    N   47

659     14  7.52    N   41

5487    14  25.75   Y   52

4326    38  7.54    N   36

1267    76  8.29    N   40
```

Comment: @LPs: probably with embedded spaces ;-)

Comment: Show file of emp_data.txt.

Comment: `scanf` is wrong. You have pointers passed to function so: `fscanf(data, "%d%d%f%d%d", &empid, &dept, &paygr, &exe, &hours);` --> `fscanf(data, "%d%d%f%d%d", empid, dept, paygr, exe, hours);`

Comment: It's now showing no errors in the Build log, but I still have the same issue reading the file. Updating the displayed code now.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems in your code:

- The variables should be made local in the `main` function.
- testing `!data` and `data == NULL` is redundant: both expressions are equivalent.
- The employee status is a character, it should be parsed with a `%c` format into a `char` variable
- you should pass values to `printf` instead of addresses.
- you should pass the data `printdata` by value too, passing the addresses is unneeded.
- input arguments in calcpay should be passed by value.  Only output variables need be passed by address.
- you must set `overpay` to `0.0` if there is no overtime, otherwise it in uninitialized or keeps the value from the previous employee.
- Printing floats value representing money should be done with 2 decimal places, not the default 6. Due to the lack of precision of the type, you could end up with `123456.799999` instead of `123456.80`.
- the linefeed character is represented as `\n`, not `/n`
- `fscanf()` ignores white space when reading values, but you should separate the values when printing them.
- The number of conversion specifiers does not match the number of arguments to `printf`. Compile with warnings enabled to let the compiler detect these silly mistakes.

Here is how to correct the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getdata(FILE *data, int *empid, int *dept, float *paygr, int *exe, int *hours);
void calcdata(float paygr, int exe, int hours, float *pay, float *overpay, float *tpay);
void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, int exe, int hours, float pay, float overpay, float tpay);

int main(void) {
    FILE *data;
    int empid;
    int dept;
    float paygr;
    char exe;
    int hours;
    float pay;
    float overpay;
    float tpay;

    data = fopen("emp_data.txt", "r");

    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open input file\a\n");
        exit(101);    
    }

    while (getdata(data, &empid, &dept, &paygr, &exe, &hours)) {
        calcdata(paygr, exe, hours, &pay, &overpay, &tpay);
        printdata(empid, dept, paygr, exe, hours, pay, overpay, tpay);
    }

    fclose(data);

    return 0;
}

int getdata(FILE *data, int* empid, int* dept, float *paygr, char *exe, int *hours) {
    int ioResult;

    ioResult = fscanf(data, "%d%d%f %c%d", &empid, &dept, &paygr, &exe, &hours);
    if (ioResult == EOF) {
        return 0;
    } else
    if (ioResult != 5) {
        printf("\aError reading data\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void calcdata(float paygr, char exe, int hours, float *pay, float *overpay, float *tpay) {
    int overhrs;

    if (exe == 'N' || hours > 40) {
        overhrs = hours - 40;
        *tpay = (paygr * (hours - overhrs)) + (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
        *pay = (hours - overhrs) * paygr;
        *overpay = (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
    } else {
        *tpay = hours * paygr;
        *pay = hours * paygr;
        *overpay = 0.0;
    }
}

void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, char exe, int hours,
               float pay, float overpay, float tpay) {
    printf("%d %d %2f %c %d %2f %2f %2f\n",
           empid,  dept,  paygr, exe, hours, pay, overpay, tpay);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. However I still have the same problem as before, it isn't reading the data from the file. I still get the "Error reading data" message.

Comment: @dazedandconfusedeestudent:  Did this answer fix your problem?

Comment: @dazedandconfusedeestudent: You can then accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems reading the file -supposing you give the correct file path at fopen(... ), try the following complete code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


  int getdata(FILE *data, int *empid, int *dept, float *paygr, char 
 *exer,int *hours);



   void calcdata(float paygr, char *exer, int hours, float *pay, float 
  *overpay, float *tpay);

  void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, char *exer, int hours, 
  float pay, float overpay, float tpay);

  int main(void) {
  FILE *data;
  int empid;
  int dept;
  float paygr;
  char exea[2];
  int hours;
  float pay;
  float overpay;
  float tpay;
  int ioresult;
  data = fopen("emp_data.txt", "r");

  if (data == NULL) {
     printf("Could not open input file\a\n");
     exit(101);    
  }

  while (getdata(data, &empid, &dept, &paygr, &exea[0], &hours)) {
     calcdata(paygr, &exea[0], hours, &pay, &overpay, &tpay);
    printdata(empid, dept, paygr, &exea[0], hours, pay, overpay, tpay);
    }
   fclose(data);

  return 0;
 }


 int getdata(FILE *data, int* empid, int* dept, float *paygr, char *exer, 
 int *hours) {
  int ioResult;
  ioResult = fscanf(data,"%d%d%f%s%d",empid,dept,paygr,exer,hours);
  if (ioResult == EOF) {
      return 0;
  } else
  if (ioResult != 5) {
      printf("\aError reading data\n");
      return 0;
   } else {
         return 1;
  }
  }

  void calcdata(float paygr, char *exer, int hours, float *pay, float  
  *overpay, float *tpay) {
  int overhrs;

  if (exer[0] == 'N' || hours > 40) {
     overhrs = hours - 40;
     *tpay = (paygr * (hours - overhrs)) + (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
     *pay = (hours - overhrs) * paygr;
     *overpay = (overhrs * (paygr * 1.5));
     } else {
             *tpay = hours * paygr;
             *pay = hours * paygr;
             *overpay = 0.0;
           }
     }

    void printdata(int empid, int dept, float paygr, char *exer, int hours,
             float pay, float overpay, float tpay) {
     printf("%d %d %f %s %d %f %f %f\n",empid,  dept,  paygr, exer,  
     hours,pay,overpay,tpay);
     }
```

That will work.